# Adding a new administrator account without password

Tags: macos, terminal, permission, administrator

This has been answered repeatedly, but I keep running into a problem. I am trying to add a new administrator account to my computer via the single-user mode in the terminal.

The `/sbin/mount -uw /` command works fine. However, whenever I type in `rm /var/db/.applesetupdone`, it gives me an override prompt. I have typed in 'yes', 'y', and 'override'. 'Yes' and 'y' both give me this message: `rm: /var/db/.applesetupdone: Permission denied`. 'Override' does nothing.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Preserve case even if the filesystem is not case sensitive. The file is named .AppleSetupDone. How does removing this file help you add a new administrator account?

Comment: First, run `mount` with no arguments, and make sure "/" isn't listed as readonly. Second, try `ls -ldeO /var/db /var/db/.AppleSetupDone`, and see if it shows any weird permissions or flags. /var/db should have the "sunlnk" flag, but that's all.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing a step, namely the `/sbin/fsck -fy` command. After logging into Single-User Mode, enter the following commands in the order listed:

1. `/sbin/fsck -fy`
2. `/sbin/mount -uw /`
3. `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone`

This should negate the need to override.